# Drawing randomly from range - is a uniform distribution possible?

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, random-generation

The specific task is to draw 5 random samples in the range of 0 to 90 with a minimum disstance of 7 between each sample.
I performed 1 million runs with respect to the conditions. The first image shows, how often each value was drawn. I was aiming for a uniform distribution, which is clearly not the case.

I tried several techniques, which improved the distribution. Nevertheless, the peaks at the front and end of the range did not disappear. (At least when 1 mio runs are performed. In an experiment with only 10k runs, no peaks at the edges of the range were visible)

Now my question is:

Given the conditions of a fixed range and a minimum distance between samples: **Is it even possible, that the drawn numbers are equally distributed?**

first attemmpt: 1 million runs with original conditions:
[image: first attemmpt: 1 million runs with original conditions]

1 Million runs: best result with new technique:
[image: 1 Million runs: best result with new technique]

Comment: For the numbers 1 to 7 and 84 to 90 there are less numbers that occur within that specified distance of them, and so samples containing these numbers are more likely to meet your conditions.

Comment: It should be absolutely possible to generate random numbers such that *you always draw 5 numbers, and repeat until you get a set where all pairwise differences are at least 7, and the end result is uniform*. However, the key is to start with a non-uniform distribution, specifically one that is modified at the left and the right. The modification will need to be specific to your sample sizes of 5.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @8e9yQBKVlIDwoIVegfkJ
. I understand your point and  I unsterstand why the ditribution looks like this. 
I tried extending the range or purposly  drawing samples out of range on to limit the possibility of chosing the numbers beween 1-7 and 84-90. This was what led to the improvements.

Comment: @StephanKolassa thank you for your answer! I did not think about starting from a non-uniform distribution!

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer, but is too long for a comment and may be helpful.

**All valid samples of length 5:** I have written some Python code which generates all the valid samples of length 5 (see below).

- There are 6471002 valid samples.
- I counted the occurrence of each of the numbers from 1-90 in the valid samples. You can see the true distribution in the graph below. Unsurprisingly, it is very similar to what you got from the random sampling.

[image: Graph showing frequencies of numbers 1-90 in the valid samples of size 5]

A few interesting things to call out:

- The rarest numbers are the numbers 8 and 83 (316251) and the most common are 1 and 90 (521855).
- What was not visible from the images due to random sampling from the OP but is in the graph above (if you zoom in), is how *bumpy* the distribution is. For example 15 occurs more frequently than 14 and 16.

**Is it possible to randomly choose from these valid samples in such a way that each number 1 - 90 is equally likely to occur?**
I think this seems unlikely. Let's consider a much smaller example, where we have the numbers 1 - 10 and want sets of size 2 with a distance of at least 7 between the numbers. Then the valid sets are $\{1,10\}, \{1,9\}, \{2,10\}$. It is clear that if each of these three samples were equally likely to be chosen, then we would see the number 1 more often than the number 2. *But perhaps we can weigh these three sets in such a way as to make each number equally likely?*

Imagine we have some process to sample between these three things (e.g. weighting them), where the probability of choosing each of the sets is $p_1, p_2, p_3$ respectively.
Then the probabilities for each number are as follows:

- $1: p_1 + p_2$
- $2: p_3$
- $9: p_2$
- $10: p_1 + p_3$

Then the only way for these four numbers to all be equally likely to occur is if $p_1 = 0$ and so the (valid) sample of $\{1,10\}$ is never chosen. *I am not sure if such a situation where valid samples are not chosen would be acceptable to the OP?*
Additionally, in this example we also have no samples containing certain numbers (3,4,5,6,7,8).

It is not clear to me how in the OPs situation, we can be sure that there does exist a way to sample from the valid samples, such that the end result is that every number from  1 - 90 is equally likely to be chosen. Also, even if it is possible and acceptable to find some weighting like I did in the small example above, I am not sure *practically* how easy it would be to find it.

**Python code:** This code is not optimised, but I hope it is clear. It is loosely based on dynamic programming, it runs in about 2 minutes on a macbook air.

```
def is_minimum_distance_greater_than_7(numbers):
    """
    Checks if the minimum distance between any two numbers in the sorted list is greater than 7.

    :param numbers: An iterable of numbers.
    :return: True if the minimum distance between any two numbers is greater than 7, False otherwise.
    """
    # Convert to list and sort
    sorted_numbers = sorted(list(numbers))

    for i in range(1, len(sorted_numbers)):
        if sorted_numbers[i] - sorted_numbers[i - 1] <= 7:
            return False
    return True
# Example usage
# is_minimum_distance_greater_than_7({1,9})
def remove_duplicates(sample_list):
    # Convert each set to a tuple and add it to a set to remove duplicates
    unique_tuples = set(tuple(sorted(s)) for s in sample_list)

    # Convert the tuples back to sets
    return [list(t) for t in unique_tuples]

# Example usage
# original_list = [[1, 2], [3, 7], [1, 2], [7,3,4,5], [3,4,5,7]]
# unique_list = remove_duplicates(original_list)
# print(unique_list)  # Output: [{1, 2}, {3, 7}]
# Creating a dictionary with keys from 1 to 5, each key mapping to an empty list
dictionary = {key: [] for key in range(1, 6)}
# Updating the list under the key 1 to be a list of lists, where each inner list contains a single number from 1 to 80
dictionary[1] = [[i] for i in range(1, 91)]
# The key is the length of the list. We begin by initiatilising all lists of length 1
# Then dictionary[2] will eventually contain all the valid lists of length 2, and so on.
# Creating new lists based on the existing lists under key 1 and adding each number from 1 to 80 to these lists
# This took less than 2 minutes to run on a Macbook Air
for j in range(2,6):
    new_lists = []
    for index, existing_list in enumerate(dictionary[j-1]):
        if index % 5000 ==0:
            print("Current list length:", j, "index", index, "/", len(dictionary[j-1]))
        for i in range(1, 91):
            candidate = existing_list + [i]
            if len(set(candidate)) == len(candidate) and is_minimum_distance_greater_than_7(candidate):
                new_lists.append(candidate)

    # Updating the dictionary with these new lists under key 1
    print("deduping")
    dictionary[j] = list(remove_duplicates(new_lists))

final_list = dictionary[5]
# Now you have all possible valid samples, you can use them as you wish.
len(final_list)
```